# Como acomodar datos en bd de pago de servicios

Tags: mysql

estoy creando/modelando una base de datos para un sistema de television por cable, donde estan involucrados pagos de facturas y contrataciones, estoy hecho un desastre y queria ver si me podrían orientar.
Hasta ahora llevo esto, con ayuda de otros foros,ya que no me quedaba (ni me queda completamente claro aun) el proceso de pago de facturas.

Estoy estancado en lo sig:

Dependiendo del tipo de accion, en este caso una contratación de servicio o un pago de mensualidad se generan diferentes cosas.

Para el pago de mensualidad se genera una factura previa cada dia 1 de mes.
Al proceder con el pago de esa factura, se cambia su estatus a "PAGADA" y ahí se guarda el pago en las tablas 'pago' y 'descrPago', pero el en la descripción del pago debe veni explicitamente "MENSUALIDAD (Lo que tenga contratado) (mes), por ejemplo:

**"MENSUALIDAD TV"**

Ahora bien, si la accion es contratar algun servicio, al registrar el pago la descrPago debería decir:

**"CONTRATACIÓN TV"**

Esto con la finalidad de al hacer una consulta de cuantas MENSUALIDADES DE TV se pagaron o cuantas CONTRATACIONES DE TV se pagaron pero  no tengo idea de si se pueda simplificar de otra forma o si el modelo esté mal.
[image: DIAGRAMA ACTUAL]

Comment: Es dificil darte una respuesta "correcta" a esta pregunta. Tu modelo "pareceria" funcionar, pero esta clase de preguntas es muy dificil de contestar, ya que armar un modelo de base de datos depende de muchisimas cosas, entre las cuales estan todas las reglas de negocios, de las cuales solo describiste dos, y el diccionario de datos, o sea que datos necesitas en cada tabla. Tu modelo "pareceria" estar bien.